# Flutter Text beside Icon doesn't want to properly apply TextOverflow.ellipsis

Tags: flutter, dart

I need a line of text preceded by an icon, and in case the line is too long, it should complete with ellipsis (...).

[Breaking to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPm2h.png)

Here is my code:

```
  Flexible _buildAddress() {
return Flexible(
  child: Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    children: [
      Icon(Icons.location_on, size: 20, color: Colors.grey,),
      SizedBox(width: 5.0,),
      Text(
        'Lorem ipsum long very long line of text',
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.grey,
          fontSize: 16.0,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}
}

Detail: the ellipsis does work properly if I only have the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap the `Text` widget with a `Flexible` widget instead:

I added a demo using your code as an example:

```dart
           return Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: [
                  Icon(
                    Icons.location_on,
                    size: 20,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 5.0,
                  ),
                  Flexible( // new line
                    child: Text(
                      'Lorem ipsum long very long line of text ddss',
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

RESULT:
[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

You can add `Flexible` or `Expended` widget on top of the `Text` widget:

```dart
_buildAddress() {
  return Container(
    child: Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
        Icon(
          Icons.location_on,
          size: 20,
          color: Colors.grey,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 5.0,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Text(
            'Lorem ipsum long very long line of textLorem ipsum long very long line of text',
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.grey,
              fontSize: 16.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: @Leonidas Yopan, do you check this? it will work hopefully.

Comment: Hey Evan. Thanks so much. I had already used @void's reply. Thanks so much for helping out.